# Which is preferred for doing async? Delegation or Blocks?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, callback

I have a model `Model` which loads some stuff via a JSON API and then I display it somehow in the UI. Say that there's only one `current` instance a a time (fetched from the server based on the time), so I have a method call that looks something like this `[Model current]`.

The problem is that I need to do something when the data loads, which leads me to two possible solutions:

1. Delegation - something like `[Model currentWithDelegate:self]` where I would implement a protocol on `self` that would have the callback
2. Blocks - `[Model currentWithSuccess:^(id response) { ... } error:^(NSError *error) { ... }]`

Since I'm a JavaScript/Ruby developer I am quite used to doing `2.`, but considering how often delegation is used on iOS I'm thinking if this is the right approach here as well?

**What is the de-facto standard or best practice for handling async on iOS?** Is there another, better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that since you are only doing two things (report success or failure), a delegate would be overkill, also if you use a block it will improve readability, since you could easily see while reading through the code what is going to be executed in two cases with out having to search for it.

This could be useful (emphasis mine): http://stablekernel.com/blog/blocks-or-delegation/

> If I look at NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, I see messages that say things like “I’m starting to do this,” “Here is what I know so far,” “I’ve finished doing this,” or “DEAR GOD THE WORLD IS ENDING, DEALLOC! DEALLOC! DEALLOC!” These messages outline a process where an interested delegate will want to be informed at each step.
>
> When I look at handler and completion methods, I see a block that contains a response object and an error object. **There isn’t any communication for “Here is where I am so far, and I’m still working.”**
>
> Thus, we can say that **delegate callbacks are more process oriented** and **blocks are more results oriented**. If you need to be informed along the way of a multi-step process, you’ll probably want to use delegation. If you just want the information you are requesting (or details about a failure to get the information), you should use a block. (If you combine this with item 3 in this list, you’ll realize that the delegate can maintain state across all of these events whereas multiple stand-alone blocks could not.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are useful for different reasons.

Blocks can be useful if you want to be able to include your callback code alongside your object allocation, and when you only have one or maybe two different callbacks.

Delegates are nice when you want to potentially have a different object handle the callbacks, or have one object handle callbacks for a variety of other objects (of course you could still do this with blocks, but it's more natural with the delegate pattern). Delegates are also nice because you have a clearly defined protocol, useful if you have many different callbacks (some of which may be required, some which may be optional), which would necessitate many block properties.

Generally I tend to use blocks most of the time in my own code, but if you find a case where delegates make more sense, use those instead.